# What packages are new to TeXlive 2024?

Tags: packages, texlive

As it seems there is no comprehensive document that explains the new changes to `TeXlive` 2024 (released on 13 March 2024), could anyone address the list of

1. the `packages` added to this release, and
2. the `packages` of `TeXlive` 2023 (released on 19 March 2023) which are no longer available?

It is important to identify new `packages` to verify whether there is a faster and simpler way to meet our needs.

Comment: Changes to the engines have been minor. Packages are added or removed during updates. Just `texdoc texlive` and go to section 9.2.

Comment: To a good approximation, nothing is ever removed from TL other than for license reasons

Comment: @JosephWright If I recall, TeXlive 2020 (plus or minus one) had changes that affected some packages. The problem is that individual packages are not always maintained.

Comment: @rallg Yes, but they don't get removed. It's not clear what you mean by TL having changes. TL just distributes stuff. I don't see how changes to TL could affect packages, if that means affecting how they work or whatever. More likely, there were changes to LaTeX (or to other packages).

Comment: Stuff gets added to TL all the time. It doesn't just happen once a year. TL itself just distributes a whole bunch of software developed by other (or the same) people. Much of that software gets updated in TL and new stuff gets added all the time, except for a brief period before the year's official release.

Comment: @cfr Indeed. When I wrote that TL had changes, I really meant "the underlying LaTeX code had changes."

Comment: @rallg I suspected you might. But the question seems to involve some confusion about what TL is, so I thought it might be better to clarify things. I suspect the OP isn't much interested in the changes to TL itself.

Comment: Even the edited question is still problematic. Do you mean packages in the initial releases of each? Packages in the final 2023 versus initial 2024? Or packages in the final 2023 versus current 2024? If the latter, the answer will likely have changed before you read it. If you do a net install (default for many systems), you will never even have the initial release. What you get will depend on when you install and (possibly) which mirror you get.

Comment: @Abbas You can check https://lists.dante.de/pipermail/ctan-ann/ for all the new packages on ctan. There are only very few exceptions which don't get added to texlive.

Comment: So you install only from the `.iso` for each release? That's the only way I can make the question make sense. Even then, it is probably not the best question. Some packages which worked with the 2023 release won't work - or won't work properly - with 2024 due to changes in LaTeX. Other packages will have been updated in ways which might be helpful or not. Moreover, LaTeX itself now provides better approaches than some existing packages. E.g. if you are using `etoolbox`, `keyval`, `xkeyval`, `environ`, `background`, `beginshi` etc., their features are superseded. (Except `etoolbox` patching.)

Comment: On Linux, you can get a list of package installed initially for the active TL installation using `less $(kpsewhich -var-value=SELFAUTOPARENT)/install-tl.log`. While `less $(kpsewhich -var-value=SELFAUTOGRANDPARENT)/YYYY/install-tl.log` will tell you what was initially installed on your system for release `YYYY`. If you used the net installer this will not be the same as the packages on the release `iso`. If you used the `iso`, it will be even if you updated later. Pretty sure you could get a list of packages in TL by searching CTAN appropriately.

Comment: `iwhdp` and `substitutefont` have been removed as obsolete. The rest look like Lua or Context and are presumably renamed/reorganised. But I don't have a complete list.

Comment: Not only new packages have new functionality. Updated packages can also have new functionality. So to find out, if you can optimize your code, you need at least reading CTAN-ANN (see samcarter's comment above) and maybe even read the manuals of all updated packages and also `ltnews.pdf`.

Comment: If you would like to keep updated on new packages, check the publications of various tex user groups. The [TUGBoat](https://tug.org/tugboat/), the [Lettre GUTenberg](https://www.gutenberg-asso.fr/-Lettre-GUTenberg-) and the [TEXnische Komödie](https://www.dante.de/dtk/) all have segments about new packages. I don't think it makes much sense to replicate these lists here.

Comment: Thanks to all guys trying to help. Actually, I install TeXlive by `iso` file as `cfr` mentioned. Also, it is understandable that updated packages may have new functionality; but the case is that the updated packages have clear scopes. For example, no one intends a new mathematical feature in a `tabular` package. A completely new package may have any scope. So, my goal is that to be aware of new packages in OFFICIAL ANUAL RELEASE.

Comment: I know that the `TeXlive` packages are being continuously updated during a year; but, this is not a good reason for `TeXlive` not to have an official documentation for `What's new in TeXlive 2024...`, otherwise the ANUAL RELEASE has no meaning. Anyhow I got my answer through some comments and I wish I had the opportunity to select them as the best answer. Thanks to all